# video tag loadedmetadata event don't apply to multiple video tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webrtc

In a single html page there are multiple video tags and all these videos may be played simultaneously. I have build an application where I am capturing video using webrtc and video capture device. These video are not seekable.
So I am calling below code for each of those video tag so that video which are playing can be seekable.

This code works fine if I apply to only one tag but when I apply it for multiple video tag it wont work.

```
$scope.addListenerVideo = function(videoSrc) {

        var videoSrcVar = document.getElementById(videoSrc);    
            if(videoSrcVar !=null) {
                videoSrcVar.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
                    if (videoSrcVar !=null && videoSrcVar.duration === Infinity) {
                      videoSrcVar.currentTime = 1e101;
                      videoSrcVar.ontimeupdate = function() {
                        videoSrcVar.currentTime = 0;
                        videoSrcVar.ontimeupdate = function() {
                          delete videoSrcVar.ontimeupdate;
                        };
                      };
                    }
                  });
            }
    }
```

html code sample:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="first-column">
            <video width="636" height="380" controls preload="auto" ng-show="actStatus_1" id="demoVideoSrc1" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; "></video>
            </div>
            <div class="second-column">
            <video width="600" height="380" controls preload="auto" ng-show="actStatus_2" id="demoVideoSrc2" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 149px;"></video>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I switched to mozilla firefox. There is issue with the way video capture in chrome which is not allowing video to be seekable. I don't know whether I was missing something or not. Once I switched to Firefox browser there was no issue with seeking video.